# Gradient scroll with RGBA-color?

Tags: html, scroll, gradient, rgba

I'm trying to figure out how to send RGBA-value into the DOM on scroll with my "Gradient scroll-box". I get that RGBA is HTML5. But why can't I send the new value as rgba into my markup when scrolling? I want the alpha to be 0.5 at all time... Got any ideas?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>Fancy Gradient scroll</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(57, 166, 221, 0.5);
    height: 5000px;
}
div {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function gradientScrollBox() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    var animation_begin_pos = 0;
    var animation_end_pos = 5000;
    var beginning_color = new $.Color("rgba(57, 166, 221, 0.5)");
    var ending_color = new $.Color("rgba(135, 200, 10, 0.5)");
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos) {
            // Calculate rgb-value depending on start and end-color.
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / (animation_end_pos - animation_begin_pos);
            var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ((ending_color.red() - beginning_color.red()) * percentScrolled);
            var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ((ending_color.green() - beginning_color.green()) * percentScrolled);
            var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ((ending_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue()) * percentScrolled);
            var newColor = new $.Color(newRed, newGreen, newBlue);

            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
        } else if (scroll_pos > animation_end_pos) {
            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
        } else if (scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos) {
            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcrreLz2/)

As you can see in my fiddle, the color I've been given in the stylesheet is set to rgba(57, ... 0.5); But as soon as I start scrolling, the value changes to only rgb, and the alpha is not there anymore. Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem by adding a variable with a value of the alpha.

```
$(function gradientScrollBox() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    var animation_begin_pos = 0;
    var animation_end_pos = 5000;
    var beginning_color = new $.Color("rgba(57, 166, 221, 0.5)");
    var ending_color = new $.Color("rgba(135, 200, 10, 0.5)");
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos) {
            // Calculate rgb-value depending on start and end-color.
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / (animation_end_pos - animation_begin_pos);
            var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ((ending_color.red() - beginning_color.red()) * percentScrolled);
            var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ((ending_color.green() - beginning_color.green()) * percentScrolled);
            var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ((ending_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue()) * percentScrolled);
            var newColor = new $.Color(newRed, newGreen, newBlue);

            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
        } else if (scroll_pos > animation_end_pos) {
            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
        } else if (scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos) {
            $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

By doing this: `var alpha = 0.5;`

and placing it here `var newColor = new $.Color(newRed, newGreen, newBlue, alpha);`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can trigger a class change on document scroll and change the color according to that class in CSS like this :

DEMO

```
    jQuery :

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $('.sticky-nav').addClass('scrolled');
        });
    });

CSS :

.sticky-nav.scrolled{
    background: gold;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were looking for that